# What's the exact meaning of »bepöbeln«?

Tags: verb, german-to-english

The below paragraph comes from the article “[Trump über Demonstranten: ‘Warum haben diese Leute nicht gewählt?](http://www.spiegel.de/politik/ausland/donald-trump-ueber-demonstranten-warum-haben-diese-leute-nicht-gewaehlt-a-1131162.html)’” in *Der Spiegel*:

> Nur einen Tag nach seiner Amtseinführung waren Hunderttausende in den
>   USA gegen Donald Trump auf die Straße gegangen. Kein Wunder, dass das
>   dem neuen Präsidenten nicht schmeckte. Seinen Pressesprecher ließ er
>   am Samstag Medien **bepöbeln**, die berichtet hatten, dass an der
>   Vereidigung des Republikaners in Washington vergleichsweise wenig
>   Menschen teilgenommen hatten - weniger als bei den darauffolgenden
>   Protesten an gleicher Stelle.

No online dictionary, including *dict.cc* and *The Duden*, has an entry for *bepöbeln*. So, what does it exactly mean? From the context, the verb seems to mean *to criticize (sb.)* or *to take (sb.) to task*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[*Pöbeln*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/p%C3%B6beln) is a word that I would associate with slang speech, loosely meaning *provoking a fight.* Somebody who *pöbelt* is typically insulting, maybe poking fists at you, saying things that are supposed to make you fight back.

The prefix *be-* does what it usually does, namely signify that somebody is on the receiving end and we are more interested in them than the active party. Thus the translation is something along the lines of:

> He made his press speaker insult and provoke the media that had reported …

The word *(be)pöbeln* clearly implies that you think negatively of the people doing so. To the best of my knowledge, this negative implication is not part of *to criticise* or *to take somebody to task.*

Comment: Das Wort impliziert keineswegs dass man negativ über den denkt, der pöbelt. Beispielsweise gibt es in der Heute-Show einen Schauspieler, der regelmäßig Gott und die Welt bepöbelt. Es lässt sich schlecht bestreiten, dass sein Handeln als Pöbeln zu klassifizieren ist. Es zielt aber auf Zustimmung beim Zuschauer.

Comment: @userunknown Die andere Antwort, die keinen Downvote bekommen hat, beschreibt es mit »unqualifiziert« und »primitiv« – beides Wörter, die negativ konnotiert sind. Diesen Eindruck macht das Wort auch auf mich. Daher ist mir deine Folgerung nicht ganz klar.

Comment: Wenn man nicht anders kann, als überall negative oder positive Konnotationen zu wittern und diese Zuschreibungen absolut zu setzen. Des weiteren die Bewertung der Handlung auf die Person zu übertragen, die sie vollzieht und zu erwarten, dass es alle Welt Dir gleich tut. Dass ich das beispielsweise nicht tue dürfte sich ja aus meinem Kommentar ergeben. Allerdings machst Du mich zurecht darauf aufmerksam, dass auch qualifiziertes Pöbeln möglich ist und primitiv muss es auch nicht sein. Weil es sich meist um emotionale Ausbrüche handelt ist es aber selten elaboriert.

Answer (score 8):

"Pöbeln" is best translated with "unqualified primitive verbal attacking" and "be" is a prefix that shows that "pöbeln" is done to someone or something, in this article it is done to the media.

Comment: @userunknown added it